# How can I fix Mpdf overWrite() not working?

Tags: php, yii2, preg-replace, overwrite, mpdf

I want to *replace a certain text from a pdf file*, then I use [***Mpdf:: overWrite()***](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/overwrite.html) to solve this. However, after I run the code, it does generate **a new file** but **remains the old content**. How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
$filePath = Yii::getAlias('@backend') . '/web/uploads/candidate_file/test1.pdf';
$mpdf = new Mpdf();
$destination = Yii::getAlias('@backend') . '/web/uploads/candidate_file/tesssssst1.pdf';
$search = ['0857598878'];
$replacement = ['Protected Phone'];
$mpdf->OverWrite($filePath, $search, $replacement, 'F', $destination);
```

Did I make any mistakes? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

manual says:

> Note: OverWrite() has **only** been tested to work on **PDF files produced
> by mPDF**. It will work with encrpyted files, as long as the same
> encryption properties are used for the new document.